# Can I append csv end xlsx files to the same list in Python?

Tags: python

Imagine you have the same structure of table in a xlsx file and a csv. Can I append it together?

Something like this:

```
filesList = ['file.xlsx', 'file.csv']
files = []

for file in filesList:
    if file.suffix = 'xlsx':
        a = pd.read_excel(file)
    if file.suffix = 'csv'
        a = pd.read_csv(file)

files.append(a)
```

Comment: It should be a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: There's no `Pandas.read_xlsx` or `string.suffix`. Have you tried actually solving the problem ? Just try to load a single Excel file?

Answer (score 3):

There is no suffix attribute for Python strings. Pandas does not have a read_xlsx function.

You probably want something like this:

```
filesList = ['file.xlsx','file.csv']
files = [] # dataframes

for file in filesList:
  if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
    files.append(pd.read_excel(file))
  elif file.endswith('.csv'):
    files.append(pd.read_csv(file))
```